# got a problem with vertex

Tags: vertices

Hello dear Blender artists,
how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Hello, hard to say, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/5bc290c5a7be403a99111e3bd5fc3981

Comment: @ApasipepOyong: please click on "accept answer" so other users although know that the answer helped you. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's the topology that creates this curve. Your current topology:

[image]

Instead use this one:

[image]

Your current topology, with *Subdivision Surface* modifier, will create a curve between the horizontal and the vertical face, so it won't stick correctly to the mirror axis:

[image]

Comment: sorry for my late reply because it was already 2 am in my country and i felt really sleepy. so, i need to re-topology? when the surface is flat i think i dont get difficulty to re-topology but, if it is a roundcurve surface it's really hard

Comment: yes use the topology I show and it will correctly stick to the mirrored mesh